# How can I add bearer token authentication to authenticated routes

Tags: node.js, express, php-curl

Actually I have added jwt bearer token authentication to APIs written in Express nodejs. In my mern project and even testing in postman, token is added to headers successfully.But I have created project dashboard section in php curl,here in php curl token is not passed to authenticted route .                  My auth.js code is:

```
function auth(req, res, next) {
    var token = req.headers['authorization'] || req.cookies.jwtPW;
      if(!token && req.query.token){
         token = req.query.token;
         }  
      try {   
       if (!token) return res.status(401).json({ errorMessage: "Unauthorized Token" });
           jwt.verify(token,process.env.SECRETKEY,(err,payload) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('JWT Verification:', err);
          return res.status(401).json({ error: "You must have logged in" });
          }
          }
         }
     }
```

When we hit endpoint of login using username and password it generated new token and token is returned in json response.in php file I took this token value and stored token value in variable $token,then I pass this token to headers of authenticated route. But when I run this file it always throw error: you must logged in 2". given below line of code of auth.js :

```
   jwt.verify(token,process.env.SECRETKEY,(err,payload) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('JWT Verification:', err);
        return res.status(401).json({ error: "You must have logged in 2" });
      }
```

```
                                                                                                                                 I have added query params to login and authenticated route.
```

This is the php code:

```
<?php
   $loginApiUrl = "http://localhost:8080/api/users/login?token=token";
   $username = 'SulemanSohail';
   $password = '3456789';

   $data = [
       'username' => $username,
       'password' => $password,
         ];

   $ch = curl_init($loginApiUrl);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
   $response = curl_exec($ch);

 if (curl_errno($ch)) {
      echo 'cURL error: ' . curl_error($ch);
      exit;
      }
  curl_close($ch);
  $responseData = json_decode($response, true);
  if (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
      
     if (isset($responseData['token'])) {
        $token = $responseData['token'];
        echo 'Token: ' . $token;
       } else {
          echo 'Login failed. No token received.';
         }
    } else{

        }

   function isTokenValid($token) {
      $tokenData = explode('.', $token);
      if (count($tokenData) !== 3) {
        // Token format is invalid
         return false;
        }

      list(, $payload) = $tokenData;
      $decodedPayload = json_decode(base64_decode($payload), true);
      if (isset($decodedPayload['exp'])) {
        $expirationTime = $decodedPayload['exp'];
        $currentTime = time();
        return $expirationTime > $currentTime;
        } else {
          // Token does not have an expiration time
          return true;
               }
         }

      if (isTokenValid($token)) {
           echo 'Token is valid.';
          } else{
           echo 'Token is invalid or has expired.';
            }

      $apiUrl = "http://localhost/api/users/all?token=$token"; // Replace with the actual API URL

      $curl = curl_init();

      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl); // Set the URL
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Return the response as a string
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
     'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token, // Set the Authorization header with the token
      'Content-Type: application/json' // Set the content type header to JSON if required
       ));

      $response = curl_exec($curl);
```

```
                                                                                                       I tried different soltutions but couldn't accomplish task , if any body help me on it.
```

I have tried different soltutions ,token is generated successfully ,we stored it in varaible and pass it to authenticated route,but I don't know authenticated route are not taking token as it is therefore auth middleware throw error jwtverification failed in node server and in browser it is showing error "you must logged in 2".(this problem I am facing in just php in mern and postmam APIs arew working fine).
I couldn't get the exact point why this happenend, I passed same SECRETKEY to login api and auth.js middleware.

Comment: Are you passing the Bearer keyword in postman?

Comment: yes I do.Actually either i pass Bearer keyword or not in postman cookies are automatically adding the cookies.But in my mern project I have added this Bearer token to authenticate route: 'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`. Everything goes well in mern project and postman just faccing problem when I am using my API in php project

Comment: Hi I forgort to split token first before passing it in to jwt, to verify it. I made these changes:                                                                                                                         
   var token = req.headers['authorization'] || req.cookies.jwtPW;
  if (req.headers.authorization) {
     token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
      }                                                                                                                                     Now authentication works in php project also. Thank you

Comment: Thats what i am trying to say